# Wavelet coefficient thresholding

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica, wavelet

I have been doing some experimentations using wavelets on image data in both Mathematica and Matlab. I have identified some piece of code in Mathematica that seems do basically do what I want which looks as follows :

```
dwd = DiscreteWaveletTransform[imagedata, HaarWavelet[]];
thr = WaveletThreshold[dwd, {"LargestCoefficients", 100}, Automatic];
out = InverseWaveletTransform[thr];
```

The above performs wavelet thresholding by keeping only the 100 largest coefficients. What I would prefer however is Matlab code that does the same thing (or more or less the same thing).

I have been experimenting a bit with the Wavelet toolbox but without much success so far. The closest I seem to have come so far is by using `wavedec2`. I have been tinkering a bit with something like this:

```
[c,s] = wavedec2(imagedata, level, 'haar');
c1 = threshold(c, 100)  % a function that zeros everything but the 100 biggest coefficients in c.
out = waverec2(c1, s, 'haar');
```

The result is sort of similar but it doesn't seem like this is the right way to do it. I guess what confuses me are the different kinds of coefficients (detail and approximation) in play here and I'm not sure where (and how) it's appropriate to do the thresholding.

I should point out that wavelets are something very new to me and therefore any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: It should be noted that `threshold(c,100)` in the snippet above does nothing more then treat `c` as a single dimensional vector and simply zeros everything but the top 100 hundred largest (absolute) values.

Comment: Looks right to me. Is the result different from what you've expected?

Comment: @Tobias: Did you mean to use the `dwt` and `idwt` functions?

Comment: @Phonon: Well, I'm not really sure. It seems like if you increase the number of kept coefficients the mathematica snippet will much faster start to look like the original image. This is why I feel that I'm missing something.

Comment: @yoda: I have been trying to use `dwt2`. But I'm not sure if I only want to do a single-level decomposition. The thing I think I want to do is to pick the biggest coefficients globally from several levels of decomposition.

Comment: Do you have code to your threshold function? It should basically be `csorted = sort(c,'descend'); c = c .* (c>csorted(100));`

Comment: Perhaps someone could post a link to a good wavelets tutorial ...

Comment: This is an extreamly good article on Wavelets and one I used to develop a very successful wavelet transformation code. [Enjoy :]](http://paos.colorado.edu/research/wavelets/bams_79_01_0061.pdf).